# How to read files from subdir when creating python package

Tags: python

I am trying to package my code and I have a structure like

```
proj
|---- __init__.py
|---- main.py
|---- data
       |---- file_to_read.csv
```

And I am trying to use path `./data/file_to_read.csv` in `main.py`. However, that is not working as I got errors like `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:`. What should I do then?

Comment: please try ./data/file_to_read.csv

Comment: @Jesse Eh it is a typo. I was using the path you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `main.py`, the path to `main.py` itself is available as the `__file__` variable.  You can use this to construct paths to other files that you know the location of relative to `main.py`.  In your case, the path to `file_to_read.csv` can be calculated as:

```
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data', 'file_to_read.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is this the practical way to do relative loading data in a pypi package?

Comment: @Mr.cysl: It is *a* practical way.  Other ways include [the resource API from setuptools' `pkg_resources` module](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#basic-resource-access) and [`pkgutil.get_data()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pkgutil.html#pkgutil.get_data).

Answer (score 0):

Please give the nice `pathlib` library a try.

```
├── __init__.py
├── data
│   └── file_to_read.csv
└── main.py
```

## data/file_to_read.csv

```
a,b
c,d
```

## main.py

```
import pathlib

file_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parents[0].absolute()
data_path = file_path / 'data/file_to_read.csv'

with open(str(data_path)) as data_file:
    data = data_file.read().rstrip()

print(data)
```

## run it

```
$ python main.py
a,b
c,d
```